# Javascript not executing on elements in html.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a Javascript file that adds an SVG to an html element. It works both standalone and in a Python app.

When I try to add it to the Rails app the javascript doesn't seem to do anything, though I can see the minimized version of it using Firefox's Inspect sources. I have added the file to /app/assets/javascripts and application.js has `//= require_tree .`

I think the problem is probably with **my index.html.erb**, my code looks like this:

```
<script>
 var retention_data = <%= @retention_results.to_json.html_safe %>;
</script>

<div><div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="dashboard">
    <div class="row" id="retention"></div>
    </div>



    <div id="popup">
        <table></table>
    </div>
    <div id="selectioninfo">
        <table></table><button id="savedata" class="btn btn-primary">Save data</button>
    </div>           


    <script src=
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src=
    "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>

</div>
</div>
```

The javascript file adds to element '#dashboard' and works outside of Rails. Do I need to include the `<script src=...` and `<link rel=...` lines? Is there something wrong with my index.html.erb?

Comment: Are any console errors occurring? The scripts and links include is usually in your default layout file.

Comment: No errors in console. I viewed the source and it looks like scripts and links are referenced to the minimized version. I'm not sure what else to check

Comment: I assume you're doing something like `$('#dashboard').append(renderDashboard())` in the js file, which you've omitted.  Including the business logic for that should help.  Also, your js should be in js files, not inlined into the body.